# How are the User and Uri parameters in the Text API interpreted and used?

Tags: microsoft-translator

The documentation for `TranslateArray` (and others) says:

- Uri: Filter results by this URI. Default: all.
- User: Filter results by this user. Default: all.

This is obscure and does not provide clues as to what to expect from the API results for a given input for these parameters. What is the purpose of these parameters? What form does 'User' take? What is it that a Uri refers to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two parameters allow you to filter the sentence pairs collected via AddTranslation. AddTranslation does not allow you to add new sentence pairs anymore, so the parameters act only on sentence pairs collected before February 1, 2018.